# Load word (lw) in the same register

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-registers

Is it correct this MIPS assembly code?

```
lw $t0, 0($t0)
```

or it's preferred something like this:

```
lw $t1, 0($t0)
```

If it's the same, what is the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both instructions are correct and equivalent in functionality. If you no longer need the address stored in `$t0` you can go with the first.